# How to stop overscroll in Safari in this case?

Tags: html, css

I have a website-slider where every section has height of 100vh. So each section is a slide. At the bottom of the website I need to have a simple footer. It works fine in all browsers but in Safari it kind of jumps because of overscroll.

[Link to example](https://jsfiddle.net/j9kd5ohb/3/)

Gray div is an image which is outside my slider and is kind of behind all of the slides beacuse I need to change it's opacity on scroll. My footer is outside of slider as well.

```
<div class="section1">SECTION 1</div>
<div class="section2">SECTION 2</div>
<div class="section3">
  SECTION 3
</div>
<div class="bg" style="background: gray"></div>
<footer>FOOTER HERE</footer>
```

CSS

```
  * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .section3,
    .section2,
    .section1 {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      background: #000;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 15%;
    }

    .section3 {
      background: transparent;
      margin-top: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .bg {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), url(bf34577….png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    footer {
      display: flex;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0 10px;
      z-index: 9;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 65px;
      object-fit: cover;
      background: #000;
      color: #727272;
    }
```

So when overscroll is happening footer jumps up and behind it you can see an image which shouldn't happen.

It can be fixed if I give footer `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` but I don't need it to be `position: fixed`, I just need it to be at the bottom of the page.